# Configuring XAMPP on macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6)

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, mamp

On a fresh installation of macOS, I decided to use XAMPP (I have previously used MAMP (free ver.)) but I have encountered some simple issues.

1. The general tab shows IP address `192.168.64.2` but my system IP is `192.168.1.100`. Why is the IP different by default? And how can this be changed to use the same? The `"go to application page"` loads dashboard on `192.168.64.2` but I'd like to use the localhost on some port like `localhost:8888` / `127.0.0.1:8888`.
2. Trying to open `phpmyadmin` returned an access forbidden page ("... New XAMPP security concept: ..."). I looked up about it in google which showed results suggesting to edit the configuration file to allow external access. I'd like to keep it to localhost, so I guess the IP has to be changed to localhost. How can that be achieved?
3. Unlike MAMP, there is no option to set the port within the application, so I tried to look for the httpd file in `Applications->XAMPP->(show package contents)->contents->... but did not find the file. So where are the configuration files?

> P.S. Do not suggest to turn off the system provided apache server
>   (`sudo apachectl stop`)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you installed the XAMPP VM version that executes a virtual machine on macOS. Check on the XAMPP website and download the normal version.
Hope this is the case and that this info helps.